# Add profile field (usermeta) to Add New User

Tags: user-meta

Edit: Add profile field (usermeta) to user registration

I am trying to add a custom field to the Add New User page much as I have done with the user profile page like so:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3>Player information</h3>

<table class="form-table">

    <tr>
        <th><label for="team-meta">Team Name</label></th>

        <td>
            <?php 
            $status = get_the_author_meta( 'team-meta', $user->ID ); 
            $items = get_posts (array (
                'post_type' => 'team_page',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            ));
            echo '<select name="team-meta" id="team-meta">  
                <option value="">No team selected</option>'; 
             foreach($items as $item) {

            echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$status == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->post_title.'</option>';  
                } // end foreach  
            ?>

            <span class="description">Please enter the player's team name </span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users', $user_id ) )
    return false;

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'team-meta', $_POST['team-meta'] );
}
```

Basically I want whoever creates a new user to be able to add this directly without going to the user profile.

Comment: Your code works. The field appears in the form and the data is saved to the DB, though you are doing no data validation or sanitization.

Comment: How odd. This is on the page `user-new.php` right? Eventually only admin will be able to use this field to create new users but for now I can't even get it to show up. Its just in functions.php and everything else there works...

Comment: No. You've added the field to the ___registration form___ at `wp-login.php?action=register`, which by all indications seemed to be the point.

Comment: Aha! Yes, your right. I thought they were the same thing. I guess that was a pretty dumb question then ;( Any idea how to hook to `user-new.php`? I suppose I should edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add data to the form at `user-new-php`, [I believe you want the `user_new_form` hook](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/user-new.php#L325). Unfortunately, it is marked "@since 3.7.0" so it isn't in the stable release yet.

I am tempted to tell you to hack it into your site in exactly the place that it will soon appear, but that would be wrong. :) You will have to wait, or [install the subversion release](http://wordpress.org/download/svn/).

Comment: That explains why there are no articles on the subject then ;) Maybe I'll test the 3.7 beta locally so at least I can have it ready. Looks like its scheduled for release pretty soon though :)

Comment: Not having much luck using the hook. But at least its displaying on the right page. :)